# Reed-Solomon library?

Tags: php, python, qr-code, error-correction

I'm going to write a QR code generator. Should I write the Reed-Solomon error correction methods by myself, or is there any free library in PHP or Python for that?

Comment: There's a lot of API's that can do the dirty work for you: http://www.google.com/search?q=qr+code+api

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. There is an QR code library in PHP.
Check the link below:
http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Python and Google Chart](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/pygooglechart/wiki/QrCodeExample) solution.

Answer (score 0):

This came up high on google, so why not point you to this one:

https://github.com/dineshrabara/barcode

OR

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a Python package [galois](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) that extends NumPy arrays over Galois fields. The Galois field arithmetic is written in Python but JIT compiled with Numba. So the arithmetic is as fast, or nearly as fast, as native NumPy.

Included in the library are [Reed-Solomon codes](https://galois.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/galois.ReedSolomon.html#galois.ReedSolomon).